# Prevent scrolling when mobile nav menu is open?

Tags: javascript, responsive, nav

I have a simple nav menu opened from a burger.  Whilst this is open how can I prevent all scrolling on the screen?  The nav bar is 100vh and I want to prevent scrolling past it whilst it is open?

Js for the nav menu so far (nothing for scrolling)

```
const navSlide = () => {
    const burger = document.getElementById('burger')
    const nav = document.getElementById('nav')
    const navLinks = document.querySelectorAll('.nav-links li')
    
    burger.addEventListener('click', () => {
        nav.classList.toggle('nav-active')
        navLinks.forEach( (link, index) => {
            if (link.style.animation) {
                link.style.animation = ''
            } else {
                link.style.animation = `navLinkFade 0.7s ease forwards ${index / 7 + 0.4}s`
                }
    })
    burger.classList.toggle('toggle')
  })
}

navSlide()
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add `overflow-y: hidden` to the `body` element when the menu is open and remove it when you close the menu.

When opening:

```
document.body.style.overflowY = 'hidden';
```

When closing:

```
document.body.style.overflowY = 'visible';
```

EDIT:

You can use the above examples like:

```
document.body.style.overflowY = document.body.style.overflowY === 'hidden' ? 'visible' : 'hidden'; // if current styling is *hidden* then change to visible, otherwise change to hidden
```

As you are toggling the class for the navbar, I think it would be easier for you to toggle a class for the `body` element too. So you can add following code to your project:

```
burger.addEventListener('click', () => {
  document.body.classList.toggle('no-scroll')
  nav.class...
})
```

And create a CSS class named `no-scroll`:

```
.no-scroll {
  overflow-y: hidden;
}
```

Comment: thank you, i have tried this and it wont work! Where in the code should I place this? Or create a new listener?

Comment: @DanWilstrop You need to insert it into the event listener you already have, but then you would need to check if there is already the class attached to `body`. Therefore I think it's easier if you use the method I added to the answer attaching a CSS class to `body`.

Comment: thanks very much. Got it working, i needed to add position:fixed as well as overflow:y to the class but that works perfectly! Appreciate the help